# Swift/Xcode "Snake Game"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am a student learning how to code in Xcode using swift. I am currently trying to make an app similar to the snake game that hopefully everyone knows.

I am currently on a windows computer so I can't show my code at the moment. I doubt you will need it for what I'm asking.

I am trying to make my Sprite Node (Just a while square) move with a swipe of the screen in the up, down, left, right fashion just like the original snake game. I have the Gesture Recognizer set up so it prints out what direction your swiping.

How can I make the sprite node move with a swipe? I want it to move infinitely in that direction until you either 1.) hit a will and you respawn/game over or 2.) swipe in a different direction.

I assume you add velocity to the node when you swipe so you just add the code into that swipe snippet but how do I make it apply ONLY to the "snake"?

Comment: Please share what you have tried to show your efforts in solving the problem.

Comment: "I doubt you will need it for what I'm asking." We would very much need it. The answer would differs depending on how you are coding the game

Comment: Once I get on a mac tomorrow, I will include my code for you guys :)

Comment: try to add some code and then ask the question, otherwise you are asking for the complete solution.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qXgADK0q
Here is all the code for my game

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SKAction to move the snakeHead toward the wall that corresponds to the direction you want to move. This can be done in the action parameter when you declare your gestures.

I suggest using .move(to: duration:) and to maintain a constant speed toward each wall you can use the distance, speed, time formula to calculate the duration for the .move(to: duration:) action.

Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-move